# Prestashop category-product association table allowing duplicates?

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

The table `ps_category_product` in PrestaShop has the following structure

```
 # Obtained using SHOW CREATE TABLE `ps_category_product`
 CREATE TABLE `ps_category_product` (
   `id_category` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `id_product` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `position` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   KEY `category_product_index` (`id_category`,`id_product`),
   KEY `id_product` (`id_product`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

For me is not very clear, but it seems that the fields `id_category` and `id_product` should be unique among the table, but for some reason MySQL allows me to insert duplicates:

```
mysql> select * from ps_category_product limit 10;
+-------------+------------+----------+
| id_category | id_product | position |
+-------------+------------+----------+
|          11 |          1 |        1 |
|          11 |          2 |        1 |
|          11 |          3 |        1 |
|          11 |          4 |        1 |
|          11 |          5 |        1 |
|          11 |          6 |        1 |
|          11 |          7 |        1 |
|          11 |          8 |        1 |
|          11 |          9 |        1 |
|          11 |         10 |        1 |
+-------------+------------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `ps_category_product` VALUES(11, 1, 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

### Later edit

It was a bug in prestashop. Take a look at http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFI-4397

Comment: what is duplicate in your case?

Comment: first of all this is an old question. secondly, the duplicated entry is the insert command at the end that doesn't raise any warnings even if the data is identical to the first row in the table.

Comment: I agree with you that is an old question, but it is still visited (1884 views). I see your second point now. I was not well understanding. Thank you very much

Comment: And thank you also for the edit. Now the situation is comprehensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `KEY` will not enforce a unique constraint unless you specify `UNIQUE KEY` or `PRIMARY KEY`.

Try recreating the table using the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `ps_category_product` (
   `id_category` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `id_product` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `position` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   UNIQUE KEY `category_product_index` (`id_category`,`id_product`),
   KEY `id_product` (`id_product`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

That should do the trick.

Have a look at the [MySQL CREATE TABLE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much. The fact that I missed is that a key is not unique by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The constraint should be imposed via the admin interface and underlying object code, so you shouldn't ever have a situation where there are duplicates, although it would be easy enough to write a cron job to remove any that did occur.

You could force this unique, but that doesn't solve the fundamental problem as to why this might happen.... I honestly don't see what the issue is that you're trying to solve? If you're importing products yourself, then you should use the object interface rather than writing to these tables directly, otherwise, yes - weird things might happen.

Comment: I'm using the object interface partially, in some cases I just can't use the existent code - it's quite not reusable sometimes. Also I still think it's a database design error the fact that there isn't any constraints for that.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion where the business logic should impose the contraints really. I've implemented an XML importer that uses the relevant objects and it works well having survived a few upgrades. My concern with custom code that manipulates the underlying database tables is based on the experience of using Pretashop since pre-release and knowing just how major the changes can be between versions... It's probably safe to assume that this particular table won't change much.

Comment: I found that this issue was reported as a bug and fixed in the new versions of prestashop :) http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFI-4397